# Xamarin forms, Execute command asyncronously

Tags: xamarin.forms, command

I have a command that executes an async method:

```
public ICommand LoadDataCommand => _loadDataCommand ??
                                       (_loadDataCommand = new Command<bool>(async force => await LoadData(force)));
private virtual async Task LoadData(bool forceLoad)
    {
      if(forceLoad)
         Data = await _service.LoadData();
    }
```

Now inside a view I want execute LoadDataCommand async to do some stuff on `ViewModel` Data object (I shouldn't call `LoadData()` method directly inside my view)

Answer (score -1):

Use another method which calls your async method. Dont forget to add .Result on calling method at the end.
Like:

```
public string LoadDataCaller(bool forceLoad)
    {
            respStr = LoadData(forceLoad).Result; // *** Add ".Result" Important

        return respStr;
    }

   private virtual async Task LoadData(bool forceLoad)
{
  if(forceLoad)
     Data = await _service.LoadData();
}
```

Comment: Calling `.Result` on an async Task will block the thread while waiting for the task to finish. Instead you should call the `LoadData` normally and do any other actions based on the result after the awaited task. ie. when the `Data` is set.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
//inside view event for example    
if(ViewModel.LoadDataCommand.CanExecute())   
      ViewModel.LoadDataCommand.Execute(force);
```

For ICommand async you must use events after it finishes. If you need async inside ICommand, you can do this:

```
public override ICommand ContinuarCommand 
{ 
    get { 
        return new Command(async () =>{ //Your async code }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to call it in sync mode, I'm looking for async mode

Comment: You can use asyn inside Icommand like this.

´public override ICommand ContinuarCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>{});
            }
     }`
 but the only way to call ICommand asyncronously y use event or token. before and after.